# NativeScript: Uninstall macOS + Android development environment

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-cli

I made the "mistake" of installing the Android development environment on my mac and tried to undo it by removing NaticeScript-CLI, Node, OpenJDK & Brew completely, before reinstalling the IOS development environment. However when I run the `ns doctor ios` command I still get references to Android environment elements which doesn't seem correct. Am I missing something or is this how it works?

```
@Macmini ~ % ns doctor ios
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 13.1.0 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 8.1.4 version and is up to date.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 13.1.0 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✖ The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android. 
 To be able to perform Android build-related operations, set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable to point to the root of your Android SDK installation directory. 

✖ WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.  
 For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements 

✖ WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly. 
 You will not be able to run your apps in the native emulator. To be able to run apps
in the native Android emulator, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK 
and its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements 

✖ Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28 or later. 
 Run `$ sdkmanager` to manage your Android SDK versions. 

✖ You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=31'. 
 Run `$ sdkmanager` from your command-line to install required `Android Build Tools`. In case you already have them installed, make sure `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is set correctly. 

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')
```

Comment: Download and install Android Studio https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-android

Comment: True, installing Android Studio will get rid those annoying errors message. However I am trying to go the other way of not having any Android stuff on the Mac, I have a Windows PC for that.